# React List and Keys - How to make last added item appearing at the top?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am working on React list and keys.  But I would like to  make the last added item appearing at the top.
is there any one who can help me?

Example.

```
import { useState } from "react";
function ListsKeys() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  function handleInput() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input");
    setNames((prevState) => {
      let state = [...prevState];
      state.push(input.value);
      return state;
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2> 03// Lists& Keys </h2>
      <hr />
      <h4>- Lists & Keys</h4>
      <input id="input" />
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleInput}>
        {" "}
        Submit Name{" "}
      </button>

      {names.map((name) => (
        <div className=""> {name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default ListsKeys;
```

Comment: Reversing an array is a pretty trivial matter. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to build "reversed" array.

1. Build up the array in state in the order you want by inserting new elements at the front of the list instead of at the end.

   ```
   function ListsKeys() {
     const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

     function handleInput() {
       const input = document.getElementById("input");
       setNames((prevState) => {
         return [input.value, ...prevState]; // prepend new value
       });
     }

     return (
       <div className="container">
         <h2> 03// Lists& Keys </h2>
         <hr />
         <h4>- Lists & Keys</h4>
         <input id="input" />
         <button className="btn" onClick={handleInput}>
           Submit Name
         </button>

         {names.map((name) => (
           <div className="">{name}</div>
         ))}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Insert at the end as per normal and just reverse the array when rendering.

   ```
   function ListsKeys() {
     const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

     function handleInput() {
       const input = document.getElementById("input");
       setNames((prevState) => {
         return [...prevState, input.value]; // append new value
       });
     }

     return (
       <div className="container">
         <h2> 03// Lists& Keys </h2>
         <hr />
         <h4>- Lists & Keys</h4>
         <input id="input" />
         <button className="btn" onClick={handleInput}>
           Submit Name
         </button>

         {names
           .slice()   // copy
           .reverse() // reverse
           .map((name) => (
             <div className="">{name}</div>
           ))}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

Also, querying the DOM via `document.getElementById` is anti-pattern in React, instead you should use a React ref and access the DOMNode via an attached ref's current value.

```
function ListsKeys() {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  function handleInput() {
    const { target } = inputrRef.current;
    setNames((prevState) => {
      return [target.value, ...prevState]; // prepend new value
    });
    target.value = ""; // clear input
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2> 03// Lists& Keys </h2>
      <hr />
      <h4>- Lists & Keys</h4>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleInput}>
        Submit Name
      </button>

      {names.map((name) => (
        <div className="">{name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or better to just use local component state and convert the input to be fully controlled.

```
function ListsKeys() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  function handleInput() {
    setNames((prevState) => {
      return [name, ...prevState]; // prepend new value
    });
    setName(''); // clear input
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2> 03// Lists& Keys </h2>
      <hr />
      <h4>- Lists & Keys</h4>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="btn" onClick={handleInput}>
        Submit Name
      </button>

      {names.map((name) => (
        <div className="">{name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Dear @Drew Reese --  It it educative and works perfect. I appreciate your willingness  to mention it in several ways which will be helpful to anyones. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.prototype.reverse()` function before print the list and add items using `Array.prototype.unshift()` passing as argument the new item.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5].reverse(); //[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: This is a React question, so be aware that `.reverse` is an in-place mutation. Be sure to not mutate state/props.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the details

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reverse();

const listItems = numbers.map((numbers) =>
  <li>{numbers}</li>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```